# Add a WebFilter Spring WebFlux to paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-filter

I have a filter:

```
@Component
public class RequestIdFilter implements WebFilter {


    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        //my logic

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
```

If it was NOT WebFlux, then I would have done so:

```
@Configuration
class FilterConfig {

    private final String V1_URL_PATTERN = "/v1/*";
    private final String V2_URL_PATTERN = "/v2/*";

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestIdFilter> requestIdFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<RequestIdFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new RequestIdFilter());
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns(V1_URL_PATTERN, V2_URL_PATTERN);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

but it is impossible to do this, since RequestIdFilter implements WebFilter...

**How to specify the necessary paths to filters using WebFilter Spring WebFlux?**

Answer (score 2):

In here, you have just declared this filter as just a bean and added the Order with @Order(). Adding @Order is optional.

What you have done incorrectly here is  registering the webFilter as FilterRegistrationBean.

Here, implicitly, you are using Webflux Config as Spring boot is using WebFlux Config to register webflux. When using the WebFlux Config, the way of registering a WebFilter is declaring it as a Spring bean. Optionally you can declare order as well.

Here is the correct code

```
@Configuration
     public class RequestIdFilter implements WebFilter {


         @Override
         public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

            //my logic
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    class FilterConfig {

        private final String V1_URL_PATTERN = "/v1/*";
        private final String V2_URL_PATTERN = "/v2/*";

        @Bean
        public RequestIdFilter requestIdFilter() {
           return new RequestIdFilter();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-filters) it is enough to declare the WebFilter

I think you need a HandlerFilterFunctions

The WebFlux framework provides two types of filters: WebFilters and HandlerFilterFunctions. HandlerFilterFunction implementations will only work for Router-based ones.

There is an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-filters)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but I don't quite understand how to implement it

Comment: added more details